# The best definition of Linearly Independence

Tags: linear-algebra, definition

I was wondering about the definition of **Linearly Independent** sets of vectors of some textbooks and how it really depends on the author vision of it.

Usually we find the definition:

> A set of vectors $A=\{\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2,...,\vec{v}_n\}$ is said to be linearly independent if and only if the equation $\alpha_1\vec{v}_1+\alpha_2\vec{v}_2+...+\alpha_n\vec{v}_n=0$ has only one solution (the trivial one: $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=...=\alpha_n=0$).

This is the definition we see, for instance, in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence).

However, another sources point out for another definition:

> A set of vectors $A=\{\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2,...,\vec{v}_n\}$ is said to be linearly independent if and only if none of the vectors $\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2,...,\vec{v}_n$ can be written as a linear combination of the others.

We can find this definition on [cliffsnotes](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/algebra/linear-algebra/real-euclidean-vector-spaces/linear-independence), among other sites.

I know that both definitions are equivalent (and when an author uses one of them as **definition**, concludes the other as **theorem**), and I know also that definitions in math are not as regularized as they should.

What I would like no know is if there is a more "correct" way than the other. What motivated the concept of **Linearly Independent Set**? Maybe an explanation of this reason helps me to decide how I must write my notes.

Thanks.

Comment: When the two definitions are equiavelent how can one be 'more correct' than than other?

Comment: As they are both equivalent, they are both perfectly correct definitions. Which one is didactically better suited for teaching depends on who you are teaching.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, I used quotes on the term **correct** precisely because of it...

Comment: As for your notes, write them both... and better yet... prove for yourself why they are equivalent.  As for what originally motivated the definition...its been around for so long we probably lost the original thought process, but it is clear what it is useful for.  For describing a collection of $n$ vectors whose span is an $n$-dimensional space where no vector is redundant and the exclusion of any of the vectors results in a "smaller" space.  Why call it "*linear*" independence?  Because of the naming of the property of *linearity*.

Comment: As for a handwavy start to the proof of their equivalence, suppose $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\dots+a_nv_n = 0$ has a solution other than every coefficient being zero and suppose without loss of generality that $a_1$ is one of those nonzero coefficients.  Then by subtracting to one side and dividing by $-a_1$ (*which is allowed since $a_1\neq 0$*) we see $v_1$ is a linear combination of the others.  Reverse this to get the other implication.

Comment: I find the second definition to be more intuitive, but the first definition is often easier to work with. (And the first definition seems somehow more elegant.)

Comment: @JMoravitz, please understand I really know to prove the equivalency between the two statements. I'm just looking for a reason (if it exists) to consider one of them as primitive of the other. Right now, it seems to me, that a right answer does not exist.

Comment: When you say "motivated", are you asking about the history of the term "linear independent"?  According to [Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics](http://jeff560.tripod.com/l.html):

LINEAR INDEPENDENCE is found in 1846 in “Researches respecting Quaternions. First Series,” by Sir William Rowan Hamilton in Transactions of the Royal Irish Academy.

Comment: @RobertIsrael thanks. That's maybe a good start...

Comment: By the way I think you have a typo in your first definition, because the "equation" is not an equation.

Comment: @almaus, thanks. I corrected it already.

Comment: The question I objected to was "What I would like no [sic] know is if there is a more "correct" way than the other."  Even though you acknowledge "I know that both definitions are equivalent".  Is $6$ more accurate than "six"?  Questions about whether $p$ or $q$ is "better" or more correct, when you've established $p \equiv q$, comes down to a matter of preference, opinion, polling, etc. Nor do you offer any criteria as to what "better" means to you...More helpful for students first learning?  More concise?, etc. So don't get all bent out of shape because you asked an opinion-based question.

Comment: If you want to post an editorial on your question and its closure, please bring it up separately on [meta.mathematics.se], but please don't just "vent" there; offer arguments as to why you think this question is not opinion-based.  Better yet, improve this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the fun of it, let me add a **third** definition:

> A collection of vectors $v_1, \dots, v_n$ is linearly independent if and only if the following holds: When $v$ is a linear combination of $v_1, \dots, v_n$, that is
> $$
> v = \alpha_1 v_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n v_n,
> $$
> then the coefficients $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ are *uniquely* determined.

Each of the three descriptions has their advantages and disadvantages and I think when learning about linear independence one should learn all three of them and really understand how and why they are describing the same property (are equivalent).

A good way to introduce this topic in my opinion is with a theorem instead of a definition:

> **Theorem.** For a collection of vectors $v_1,\dots,v_n$ the following conditions are equivalent:
>
> 1. …
> 2. …
> 3. …
>
> If any one (and hence all) of the conditions is satisfied, we call the collection *linearly independent*.

Comment: So the question wasn't confusing enough?? :)

Comment: Your approach could work...

Comment: Given that we are dealing with "several" definitions, why not consider this different from the mentioned ones but equivalent, naturally. The set $A$ above (in which each $\vec {v} _i \ne0$) is linearly independent when none of its vectors belongs to the subspace generated by the others.

Answer (score 2):

Even though the two definitions are equivalent, I have often seen the first definition being used more often than the second. However, I think that the second definition is more useful since it provides an intuitive point of view for linear independence. Usually, people are first introduced to linear combinations and then to linear independence, and defining linear independence in terms of linear combinations provides a smoother transition. I should also add that I personally think that the second definition motivated linear independence. When we think about what "independent" means; it means that every vector is independent of all the others. In other words it cannot be written as a linear combination of other vectors.

Comment: But they are both in terms of linear combinations. "The only linear combination of the given vectors that yields zero is the trivial linear combination."

Comment: @Christoph, you're right, but I understand Math student. (+1) point of view. However that's not exactly the kind of answer I'm looking for.

Comment: @Pspl, I edited my answer as which one I think motivated the definition.

Answer (score 1):

To build intuition about the notion of linearly independent vectors, look first at what happens when there is a finite number of vectors in the set $S$.

Then, start from an empty new set $T$ and add the vectors of $S$ one by one:
the set $S$ is linearly independent iff each time that you add a vector (from $S$) to $T$ then the vector space generated by $T$ is strictly larger than at the previous iteration.

The order in which you add the vectors is not important, because generating the vector space from $T$ means taking all the linear combinations of the vectors in $T$. Thanks to the associativity and distributivity properties of sum and scalar product, you see that you get the same generated spaces whatever the order.

The negation of linearly independent, then, is that at some point when you add a vector (from $S$) to $T$, your resulting space generated from $T$ (by all linear combinations) does not increase at all. And that means that the added vector was already in the vector space generated from $T$ at the previous step.

So that means exactly, in the most intuitive and obvious way, that the vector (the one added at that step) is a linear combination of others in the set.

This example is taking simplified hypotheses, so the reasoning would be different with, say, vector spaces of infinite dimension, but at least you see the mechanics and the motivation behind these notions.

Comment: So what you are saying is the second definition should be primitive of the first one?

Comment: Well, it may depend on who is explaining it, but yes, following my approach the way you generate the vector space (all linear combinations) is becoming implicit, so you hide the coefficients $\alpha_k$ inside the definition of vector space itself. So yes it becomes the second definition.